# Apache to Nginx migration

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, migration, apache2

we are migrating from Apache to Nginx. Everything is setup and tested. Our whole infra is hosted on AWS.

I'm little bit nervous about the final migration as to how should I start the migration on production servers with zero downtime for our users.

We've 20 running apache servers and we want to replace them with nginx based servers. Can anyone give an insight on how to go about it?

Comment: hm, why you would ike to do so? you could use nginx as a proxy to improve and cache, and change for each site afterwards the settings one by one to a local one

Comment: @djdomi Hi djdomi. This is what we've been asked to do. We are using nginx as a stand alone server and not as a proxy with apache.

Answer (score 2):

Gradual cut over. First in the test environment, then in prod starting with one web server.

Backout plan is redirecting traffic back to the still running Apache httpd instances.

Automate and practice the cut over procedure often with many small changes. Planned change should not make you nervous.